# Batch file finds registry entry that's a path and uses it to find uninstall path

Tags: batch-file, registry, aim

I'm trying to silently uninstall AIM which is installed on a user's profile, not the machine. I'm using a batch script to find a registry entry that is the path where it's installed, then using that path to uninstall it. I'm not the best at writing scripts, but here is what I've put together.

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %%! in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\DragDrop\{7A02967B-018E-41c9-953E-3DCAB144538B}" /v "AppPath" ^|Findstr.exe /ri "\<AppPath\>"') DO (if exist %%! %%!\uninstall.exe /S /PopUpMsgBox="n" /CheckMutx="N)
```

I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: `DO` must be stated in the same line as the preceding `)`!

Comment: I thought that the location was constant, i.e. `Start "" "%LOCALAPPDATA%\AOL\AIM\uninstall.exe"`

Comment: @compo I'm uninstalling as the system, but it's installed under the user's profile.

Comment: Figured it out...no parenthesis after DO